# iPhone 6 Plus collection view not fit on screen

Tags: uicollectionview, iphone-6-plus

I understand that the screen size for iphone 6 plus would be 736x414 after adding the launch image.

Problem comes that there is always a crack between collection view items on iphone 6 plus device and no problem on simulator.

From the following image, you will see there is a gray line between shoes and  home & tech.
The width of the blocked is hardcoded by screenwidth / 2 (i.e. 207) by me.

I checked there is nothing wrong with the image since the gap appear before finish loading the images.

**DEVICE**

[image]

**SIMULATOR**

[image]

Actually there are more gaps before finish loading the images. but I guess the image provide an illusion to hide the gap. I am not sure if anyone know how to set the block size of collection view for iphone 6 plus. Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing this in scaled up apps on the iPhone 6 - are you getting it in native resolution?

Comment: yes, I did. Someone encounter similar problem in Apple forum too. https://devforums.apple.com/message/1071027#1071027

Comment: @KenHui Hey. How do u fix it finally? The link you posted is no longer accessible. (btw i like Hypebeast)

Comment: @TonyFungChoiFung It has been a long time. I don't actually remember what have I done. I remember I overrided two methods of collection view or the cell which calculate the actual size. And then it do the tricks.